# Adding parenthesis changes evaluation of condition

Tags: scheme, lisp

I'm starting to learn Scheme and stumbled on this curious thing:
Given the following procedure:

```
(define (test x y) (if (= x 0) 0 y ))
```

When I create a conditional, it evaluates "as expected" when I add parenthesis to it: `(test 0 1)` gives 0. But when I don't add parenthesis (and I use the same input) it evaluates to the false condition: `test 0 1` gives 1.

Why is this?

Comment: That's Scheme syntax. You have to use parentheses to make a function call.

Comment: I get it, but what is it in Scheme that causes it to evaluate to false? Why doesn't it just give a lexical error?

Comment: It's not evaluating to false. You're seeing what you typed, which is `1`.

Comment: You're not calling the function at all.

Comment: Experimenting a bit more, I see now that it just returns the last thing I typed in. Since I don't wrap it in parens it does not evaluate it, it just returns the input.

Comment: That's right. It's a read-eval-print loop. It reads your input, evaluates it, and prints the result. Numbers just evaluate to themselves.

Comment: I'll add this as the answer if you don't mind

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you write:

```
test 0 1
```

This is the same as:

```
(begin
  test ; evaluate variable test => #<procedure:something...> or similar value
  0    ; evaluate literal 0 => 0
  1)   ; evaluate literal 1 => 1
==> 1  ; because 1 is the last expression in the block it is the result of it.
```

When you do `(test 0 1)` you are calling the procedure you'll get by evaluating variable `test` with the two arguments `0` and `1` which gets evaluated to the numbers they represent. If you do substitution it becomes:

```
(if (= 0 0) ; if 0 is the same numeric value as 0
    0       ; then evaluate 0
    1)      ; else evaluate 1
==> 0
```

The same in JavaScript:

```js
const test = (x, y) => x === 0 ? 0 : y;
test;0;1    
==> 1        // result in node is 1 since it was the last expression

test(0, 1); // calling the fucntion behind the variable test with the arguments 0 and 1
==> 0
```

So parentheses matters around stuff as they matter afdter stuff in JavaScript. Basically `(one two three)` in Scheme is `one(two, three)` in JS. Just adding parentheses around somtheing is to just add `()` after something in JS.

Comment: thank you, thank you! I wanted an explanation of the Why, not just the How and this is what I was looking for.